# HTML/JS Carousel that changes text and images

Tags: javascript, html

I want to have a carousel with a text. Every time I click the button to the right/left, I want the image and the text to change. It works well with the images but I don't get a text. How can I change the text with every click on the buttons? I've tried with 'src' at *document.carousel_text.**src** = texts[i]* but that gets an error in the console. But only at *window.onload*.

```js
var i = 0;
var images = [];
var texts = [];

// image list
images[0] = 'src/image1.jpg';
images[1] = 'src/image2.jpg';
images[2] = 'src/image3.jpg';

// text list
texts[0] = 'Text1';
texts[1] = 'Text2';
texts[2] = 'Text3';

// change image
function changeImgLeft() {
  changeTextLeft();
  if (i > 0) {
    i--;
  } else {
    i = 2;
  }
  document.slide.src = images[i];
}

function changeImgRight() {
  changeTextRight();
  if (i < images.length - 1) {
    i++;
  } else {
    i = 0;
  }
  document.slide.src = images[i];
}

window.onload = document.slide.src = images[i];
window.onload = document.carousel_text = texts[i];

// change text
function changeTextLeft() {
  if (i > 0) {
    i--;
  } else {
    i = 2;
  }
  document.carousel_text = texts[i];
}

function changeTextRight() {
  if (i < images.length - 1) {
    i++;
  } else {
    i = 0;
  }
  document.carousel_text = texts[i];
}
```

```html
<div id="carousel">
  <button class="carousel_button" onclick="changeImgLeft()">
    <img class="carousel_button_image"src="src/left_button.svg">
  </button>
  <img id="slideImg" name="slide">
  <button class="carousel_button" onclick="changeImgRight()">
    <img class="carousel_button_image"src="src/right_button.svg"></button>
  <div id="carousel_text">
    <h1 name="carousel_text"></h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please try it:

```js
var i = 0;
var images = [];
var texts = [];

// image list
images[0] = 'https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/la.jpg';
images[1] = 'https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/chicago.jpg';
images[2] = 'https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/ny.jpg';

// text list
texts = ['Text0','Text1','Text2'];

// change image
function changeImgLeft() {
if (i > 0) {
        i--;
    } else {
        i = 2;
    }
    changeTextLeft(i);
    
    document.slide.src = images[i];
}

function changeImgRight() {
if (i < images.length - 1) {
        i++;
    } else {
        i = 0;
    }
    changeTextRight(i);
    
    document.slide.src = images[i];
}

window.onload = document.slide.src = images[i];
window.onload = document.getElementsByName("carousel_text")[0].innerText = texts[i];

// change text
function changeTextLeft(counter) {
    document.getElementsByName("carousel_text")[0].innerText = texts[counter];
}

function changeTextRight(counter) {
    document.getElementsByName("carousel_text")[0].innerText = texts[counter];
}
```

```html
<div id="carousel">
            <button class="carousel_button" onclick="changeImgLeft()">left</button>
            <button class="carousel_button" onclick="changeImgRight()">right</button>
            <img id="slideImg" name="slide">
            
            <div id="carousel_text">
                <h1 name="carousel_text"></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: It shows the text now and changes it on click of the buttons.
Every time I click on a button and then click on the other button, the image changes on the first click but the text doesn't. When I click again, both the text and the image change. So I don't have the text1 that should be displayed with image1, instead there is text3 with image1, for example. Any ideas?

Comment: if it works fine please checked my answer as correct answer.

Comment: On Safari, the images are stretched. I fixed this by taking the <img id="slideImg" name="slide"> and putting it in a p with an ID. I changed the innerHTML of the ID. Works totally fine.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap have a component that fits exactly what you are looking for.

Here is the link about it https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/carousel/

In order for this to work, you must include those tags in your HTML file:

```html
This goes on <head> tag
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

```html
This goes on <body> tag
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

What's the point of using a `name` attribute for an `<h1>`?

Try assigning it an id:

```js
var i = 0;
var images = [];
var texts = [];

// image list
images[0] = 'src/image1.jpg';
images[1] = 'src/image2.jpg';
images[2] = 'src/image3.jpg';

// text list
texts[0] = 'Text1';
texts[1] = 'Text2';
texts[2] = 'Text3';

// change image
function changeImgLeft() {
  changeTextLeft();
  if (i > 0) {
    i--;
  } else {
    i = 2;
  }
  document.slide.src = images[i];
}

function changeImgRight() {
  changeTextRight();
  if (i < images.length - 1) {
    i++;
  } else {
    i = 0;
  }
  document.slide.src = images[i];
}


// change text
function changeTextLeft() {
  if (i > 0) {
    i--;
  } else {
    i = 2;
  }
  document.getElementById('carousel_text').innerHTML = texts[i];
}

function changeTextRight() {
  if (i < images.length - 1) {
    i++;
  } else {
    i = 0;
  }
  document.getElementById('carousel_text').innerHTML = texts[i];
}

window.onload = document.slide.src = images[0];
window.onload = document.getElementById('carousel_text').innerHTML = texts[0];
```

```html
<div id="carousel">
  <button class="carousel_button" onclick="changeImgLeft()">
    <img class="carousel_button_image"src="src/left_button.svg">
  </button>
  <img id="slideImg" name="slide">
  <button class="carousel_button" onclick="changeImgRight()">
    <img class="carousel_button_image"src="src/right_button.svg"></button>
  <div id="carousel_text">
    <h1 id="carousel_text"></h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Here, it's the same problem as at in the first answer by Mehrzad Tejareh. The buttons don't work for the text on the first click so it's asynchronous.

Comment: @Berl Your carousel has more then one problem. You can use Bootstrap's carousel instead. Or cant you?

Comment: @Berl Have a look at **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64184967/4512005)** slider solution, which I came up with today, inspired by your need. Is it suitable to your need?