# How can I update the style attribute of a virtual html element with the value of a JavaScript variable?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on this JavaScript image (and text) slider.

I create a list of slides in JavaScript and append it to a div in the DOM:

```
let slidesHtml = '<ul style="width: ' + slidesListWidth + '; transform: translateX(' + translateAmount + ')">';
 for (let i = 0; i < slidesLen; i++) {
   slidesHtml += '<li style="width: ' + slideWidth + '">' + '<img src="' + slides[i].image + '" alt="' + slides[i].text + '"><span class="text">' + slides[i].text + '</span></li>';
 }
 slidesHtml += '</ul>'
 sliderControls.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', slidesHtml);
```

In the code *above*, `translateAmount` does not update when the JavaScript variable `let translateAmount = 0` changes its value (from 0 to different percentages).

```js
 let slides = [{
     text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto fugiat enim voluptate eos placeat quis veniam quod inventore ipsum sapiente vel, earum, ratione neque.",
     image: "https://picsum.photos/1200/600?gravity=east"
   },
   {
     text: "Sit quis provident reiciendis sed optio molestias impedit maiores nesciunt!",
     image: "https://picsum.photos/1200/600?gravity=west"
   },
   {
     text: "Odio mollitia inventore nostrum quasi labore architecto quis id repudiandae quidem!",
     image: "https://picsum.photos/1200/600?gravity=north"
   }
 ];

let slider = document.getElementById('imageSlider');
let sliderControls = document.getElementById('sliderControls');
let slidesLen = slides.length;
let slidesListWidth = slidesLen + '00%';
let slideWidth = (1 / slidesLen * 100) + '%';
let clickCount = 0;
let translateAmount = 0;

function updateAmount() {
  translateAmount = clickCount * 1 / slidesLen * 100 + '%';
  console.log(translateAmount);
}

function nextSlide() {
  if (Math.abs(clickCount) < slidesLen - 1) {
    clickCount--;
  } else {
    clickCount = 0;
  }
  updateAmount();
}

function prevSlide() {
  if (clickCount < 0) {
    clickCount++;
  } else {
    clickCount = 1 - slidesLen;
  }
  updateAmount();
}

let slidesHtml = '<ul style="width: ' + slidesListWidth + '; transform: translateX(' + translateAmount + ')">';
for (let i = 0; i < slidesLen; i++) {
  slidesHtml += '<li style="width: ' + slideWidth + '">' + '<img src="' + slides[i].image + '" alt="' + slides[i].text + '"><span class="text">' + slides[i].text + '</span></li>';
}
slidesHtml += '</ul>'

sliderControls.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', slidesHtml);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#imageSlider {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#imageSlider ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transition: all 1.0s ease-in-out;
}

#imageSlider li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

#imageSlider img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#imageSlider .text {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: justify;
  line-height: 1.5;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.controls span {
  width: 30px;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0.75;
  font-size: 48px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -30px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.controls span:last-child {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="imageSlider">
  <div class="controls" id="sliderControls">
    <span onClick="prevSlide()">&lsaquo;</span>
    <span onClick="nextSlide()">&rsaquo;</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I fix this bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you modify value but not the style of element (it's not data-binded as it is in for example react), so you must take your UL to variable, and then in updateAmount you should do something like

```
function updateAmount() {
    translateAmount = clickCount * 1 / slidesLen * 100 + '%';
    yourUlElement.style.transform = 'translateX(' + translateAmount + ')';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't writing anything to the DOM, you are just setting a JavaScript variable.

In your updateAmount() function you would need to get a reference to the ul element in the DOM and set the style attribute with the updated value.

That said, this is not a very nice implementation. instead of using global variables, perhaps have a go at creating an encapsulated component for this with a local state that you update on click of the next and previous buttons. Also you would improve readability a lot by using template strings instead of all those concatenations.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks @Kamil Rogala who help fix a bug that eluded my vigilance.

There is the full working slider, for whoever may need it:

```js
(function() {
  let slides = [{
      text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto fugiat enim voluptate eos placeat quis veniam quod inventore ipsum sapiente vel, earum, ratione neque.",
      image: "https://picsum.photos/1200/600?gravity=east"
    },
    {
      text: "Aperiam eligendi animi, suscipit repellendus tempore amet totam excepturi, porro facere nulla dignissimos pariatur doloribus dolorum sunt, et veritatis expedita consectetur.",
      image: "https://picsum.photos/1200/600?gravity=west"
    },
    {
      text: "Odio mollitia inventore nostrum quasi labore architecto quis id repudiandae quidem!",
      image: "https://picsum.photos/1200/600?gravity=north"
    },
    {
      text: "Iusto fugiat enim voluptate eos placeat quis veniam quod inventore ipsum sapiente vel, earum, ratione neque. Inventore nostrum quasi labore architecto quis id repudiandae quidem!",
      image: "https://picsum.photos/1200/600?gravity=south"
    }
  ];

  let slider = document.getElementById('imageSlider');
  let sliderControls = document.getElementById('sliderControls');
  let slidesLen = slides.length;
  let slidesListWidth = slidesLen + '00%';
  let slideWidth = (1 / slidesLen * 100) + '%';
  let clickCount = 0;
  let translateAmount = 0;

  function updateAmount() {
    translateAmount = clickCount * 1 / slidesLen * 100 + '%';
    document.getElementById('slidesList').style.transform = 'translateX(' + translateAmount + ')';
  }

  window.nextSlide = function() {
    if (Math.abs(clickCount) < slidesLen - 1) {
      clickCount--;
    } else {
      clickCount = 0;
    }
    updateAmount();
  }

  window.prevSlide = function() {
    if (clickCount < 0) {
      clickCount++;
    } else {
      clickCount = 1 - slidesLen;
    }
    updateAmount();
  }

  let slidesHtml = '<ul id="slidesList" style="width: ' + slidesListWidth + '; transform: translateX(' + translateAmount + ')">';
  for (let i = 0; i < slidesLen; i++) {
    slidesHtml += '<li style="width: ' + slideWidth + '">' + '<img src="' + slides[i].image + '" alt="' + slides[i].text + '"><span class="text">' + slides[i].text + '</span></li>';
  }
  slidesHtml += '</ul>';

  sliderControls.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', slidesHtml);
})();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#imageSlider {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#imageSlider ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transition: all 1.0s ease-in-out;
}

#imageSlider li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

#imageSlider img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#imageSlider .text {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: justify;
  line-height: 1.5;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.controls span {
    line-height: 1;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 30px;
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 21px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 54px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -18px;
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

.controls span:last-child {
  right: 0;
}

#imageSlider:hover .controls span {
  opacity: .75;
}
```

```html
<div id="imageSlider">
  <div class="controls" id="sliderControls">
    <span onClick="prevSlide()">&lsaquo;</span>
    <span onClick="nextSlide()">&rsaquo;</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** for an instant transition, replace `transition: all 1.0s ease-in-out` with `transition: all 0s`.